# How to host multiple subdomain on another server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

I have one webserver and one Application server.

Webserver1 have FreeBSD 8.1, Apache, MySQL and PHP.
Application1 server have Centos 5.5, Apache, Mysql and PHP.

Both server running fine independently. My webserver1 is hosting my company website www.azrim.com which running good. Besides I have 2 online application which requires me to host them as a subdomains.

My questions is I want to make subdomains such as abc.azrim.com and xyz.azrim.com is accesscible from Application1 server. Can anyone pls help me on this. What should I do on apaches configuration on both webserver1 and Apps1 server. I only have 1 NIC card on my Apps1 server.

Really appreciate anyone who got the solution. 
Thanks
Azrim

Comment: If you only have 1 NIC card, I'm not really sure what you can do.  Can the server without the NIC card connect to the network at all?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup virtualhosts on the apache server
The config will look something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost IP:80
<VirtualHost IP:80>
   ServerAdmin     EMAIL
   DocumentRoot    /PATH/TO/WEB/FILES
   ServerName      SERVERNAME
</VirtualHost>
```

It won't be exact, but that should get you on the right path.

Comment: How does he get traffic to the machine that doesn't have a NIC card?

Comment: Nevermind, his question wasn't clear initially.  1 NIC card on the apps server should work for multiple domains.

Comment: @jmort253:  I think you misread his question.  Apps1 has only one NIC.

Comment: I sure did... now it's clear :)

Comment: Do I need to config that virtualhost on my webserver1 or apps1 server?

Comment: Appserver I believe, because that is where you're using two subdomains.

Comment: what about the webserver1 apache config? Do I need to do anything?

Comment: Does it already work?  If it ain't broke, don't fix it ;)

Comment: will try it now...will let u know :)

Comment: jmort253: finally its work. thanks for giving an advise. it works fantastic like what i really need. I dont have to do anything on my webserver1. just few configs on Apps1 server only. Now I can have multiple subdomains on my apps1 server. but dont know what is the max subdomain can I have. But for me less 10 is more than enough i think

Comment: @Azrim - Glad to hear it's working! :)

Comment: hi jmort253. I got another questions. From the config that I have done was working fine where i can access abz.azrim.com and xyz.azrim.com....unfortunately i can't access it from the external IP. FYI I have done NAT IP in my firewall like others NAT server. Also configure my external DNS server to point to the correct Public IP. Others NAT Server working just fine but my subdomain server just not working to the outside world. Any idea where should I look into? really appreciate ur helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
NameVirtualHost 172.16.4.18:80


<VirtualHost 172.16.4.18:80>
  ServerAdmin abc@azrim.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/abc
  ServerName abc.azrim.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.16.4.18:80>
  ServerAdmin xyz@azrim.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xyz
  ServerName xyz.azrim.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: above is my code...kindly advise..